# How to delete and add nodes to/from Dynatree prog

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynatree, jquery-dynatree

how to delete and add nodes to/from Dynatree without disturbing other node?

I have a Dynatree with check box And a user can add / remove nodes from a list of nodes in a pop up. While updating the data should be added / remove with out disturbing the previously checked nodes.

Comment: U Can Try JStree http://www.jstree.com/  that is good tree